# Is it legal to use textures from another game, but not provide those with the new game installer?

Tags: licensing, copyright

The situation is there is some very old bugged mmorpg game that left without any improve since 2008. I doing remake of this game (with different name), but I am programmer, not graphics designer.

I came to idea what if only the exe file of the new game was distributed, and players must put the new exe into existing game folder and run it, so the new exe can use existing textures of original game? It could be called a "compatible graphics environment".

So the site of the new game will have something like that: "To play this game you need to put downloaded exe file into folder with compatible graphics environment. I do not provide anything like that. You should figure out by yourself what is compatible graphics environment for this game."

Is this legal?

Comment: I don't know if it's actually legal (though I suspect it is), but this is the strategy used by [OpenDUNE](https://github.com/OpenDUNE/OpenDUNE), a re-implementation of the game Dune II. It requires you to use media assets from your own copy of the original commercial game.

Comment: @apsillers - this is very good to know. OpenDUNE is still there, so they probably didn't had any problems with their project. Thank you.

Comment: And you could then let artists provide art that you can spread around for those that don't have the original game.

Comment: Another game that uses this model is [OpenTTD](https://www.openttd.org/en/).